# play - How to get the result in onError in Global.scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I need to access the response statuscode and other response parameters in the onError method. How would I do that?

My current onError -

```
@Override
public Result onError(RequestHeader rh, Throwable t) {  
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get anything from a response if an error occurred: The code never reached the point where a `Result` was created.